# How to debug Python Pathos multiprocessing

Tags: python, debugging, multiprocessing, pathos

I am using pathos.Pool to run multiprocessing. I try to catch multiprocessing errors and specific information of the multiprocessing errors such as the lines of the wrong codes and error types. I want the error information to be specific and detailed that can help me to debug. Thanks!

Here is the sample of my coding. In the class GeneralFlow, I use the pathos.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async().get()to do multiprocessing.

```
 try:
    General_flow = GeneralFlow(general_parameter)
 except:
    logger.critical(‘Fail to do the calculation, and the error information is:{}’.format(trace back.format_exc()))
```